# Cannot paginate using list blobs (v2) in logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm working to process a large number ( ~50,000 ) files in an Azure blob from a logic app. When I specify pagination (to on) and threshold (to 5,000), I do not see a 'Next Page Marker' in the result. My intention is to store the 'Next Page Marker' in a variable and loop through all the data until completed.

The code version is below followed by the settings for the action.

```
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('rtwsftp'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmc2Z0cC1zZXJ2ZXIlMmZ0dWNjJTJm'))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmc2Z0cC1zZXJ2ZXIlMmZ0dWNjJTJm": "/sftp-server/tucc/",
                    "JTJmdHVjYw==": "/tucc"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "paginationPolicy": {
                        "minimumItemCount": 5000
                    }
                },
```

Below is the settings I've used for the 'List blobs (V2) 2' action.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer. I needed to turn 'Pagination' off. This gave me a 'Next Page Marker' that I used in a do until loop properly.